# Cordova signed apk installs on device but only produces a blank screen

Tags: android, cordova

I built an android application and signed the apk following all the steps on this [tutorial](http://vincentpeters.be/signing-a-cordova-android-apk-from-the-command-line/). Even though the APK builds successfully after installing it on a mobile device it fails to load. I only get a white blank screen. I've searched for solutions and tried most of the suggestions but with no luck.

I then decided to start the project from scratch and guess what? the problem still persists. What could I have possible done wrong? I don't really know where to look because I don't even get an error message.

Please help???

Comment: In which folder have you done any edits? `www` root folder or under platforms -> android -> assets -> www?

Comment: None. I've only added an .html file and a couple of .js files. But when I tried editing the android:manifest <application> tag & set android:debuggable="false" it threw an error. I then cleaned the project but the error just wouldn't go away which left me with no choice but to  withdraw my edit.

Comment: And you included the cordova.js etc. into your own index.html? Or did you add another html file then the index.html?

Comment: I included it into my own html file

Comment: I'm curious though, i've been reading up on creating _release apk_ and the need to set **andoid:debuggable =false**. Since when i do that I get an error, not a warning, is it safe to assume that I won't be able to generate a correctly **singed release apk** ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try debugging that with a tool like GapDebug (https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/). I would:

1. Download and install GapDebug.
2. Attach your device to your PC/Mac via a USB cable.
3. Deploy your APK to the device and run it.
4. In GapDebug, choose your app as the app you want to debug.

At this point you may already see one or more errors showing up in the GapDebug console. If not,

5. On the device, restart the app.
6. Check the GapDebug console for errors.

Comment: If you're going to check this solution, note that `errors` thrown at the start of an application launch are not thrown into the GapDebug-Console since they're not interrupting the launch Process. To see `errors` ocurring during app launch, just click on the refresh-icon on top of the navigation bar on the left side. This will refresh your application, by just taking care of your actual debugging instance so that you can see all `errors`. Follow it this way because restarting that application on your device is just time-robbing.